# Wordpress comment reply link image

Tags: comments

I'm currently setting up comments for a Wordpress theme I'm created, I have just successfully created **nested comments** but I'm having issues removing the word '**reply**' from the reply button in order to use an image via the css.

The code I'm using at the moment for the reply link is as follows:

```
<?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
```

I need the word 'reply' to completely disappear and just rely on my css button which is as follows:

```
ol.commentlist li div.reply { width:104px;height:35px;background-image:url(images/comment_reply.png); }
ol.commentlist li div.reply:hover { background-image:url(images/comment_reply_rl.png);}
ol.commentlist li div.reply a { float:left;width:104px;height:35px;background-image:url(images/comment_reply.png); }
```

All help will be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_reply_link ?

Comment: Yes but I'm not a coder and can't get it to work without completely breaking the functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'], 'reply_text' => ''))) ?>
```

Comment: that didn't work :(

Comment: please paste the full code of your comment section into a pastebin.com and post the link to it here.